# Replace each word in webpage's paragraphs with a button containing that text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that takes all the paragraphs (p tag content) and places each words in them up into a button. It's a part of a larger program I'm working on. I have a working copy of that part of the app on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77upayvz/).

Now, I'm trying to port that code into a Chrome Extension. But, I'm having trouble accessing the DOM from my background script, so that I can manipulate it with my code (in my function `FormatText()`). I haven't even called the function yet, because I can't figure out how I'm supposed to edit the DOM in the first place within *background.js*.

Here is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js","jquery-3.0.0.min.js","TextSplitter.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs"]
}
```

**content.js**

```
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    // If the received message has the expected format...
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        // Call the specified callback, passing
        // the web-page's DOM content as argument
        sendResponse(document);
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```
// A function to use as callback
function doStuffWithDom(domContent) {
    console.log('I received the following DOM content:\n');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(domContent));
    var domAccess = $(domContent);
    var myText = $(domAccess).find("p").text();
    console.log("THIS IS MY TEXT: " + myText);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabID, info, tab) {
    console.log("Status: " + info.status);
    if (info.status == "complete") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: 'report_back' }, doStuffWithDom);
    }
});
```

**TextSplitter.js**

```
function FormatText(domObject) {
    var pElements = []; // Holds the split paragraphs for each p tag
    var pElementIndex = 0;

    //Loop through each p tag in web page
    $("p").each(function (webPElementIndex, webPElement) {
        var jQObjWebPElement = $(webPElement);// Convert p element to jQuery Obj
        // split current paragraph element text into an array of seperate words
        pElements[webPElementIndex] = jQObjWebPElement.text().split(" ");
    });

    //Clear text out of all p elements
    $("p").empty();

    //Loop through p elements in the webpage to add back text with spans around each word
    $("p").each(function (webPElementIndex, webPElement) {
        // convert current web page element to jQuery Obj
        var jQObjWebPElement = $(webPElement);
        // Loop through each word stored in each stored paragraph element
        $.each(pElements[pElementIndex], function (pElementWordIndex, pElementWord) {
            var jQObjPElementWord = $(pElementWord); // convert element to jQuery object
            jQObjWebPElement.append($("<button>")
                            .text(pElements[pElementIndex][pElementWordIndex]));
        });
        pElementIndex = pElementIndex + 1;
    });
}
```

Please pardon my ignorance as I am very new to working with the DOM in general, especially in a Chrome extension.

Comment: See the [extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): you need a content script.

Comment: Delete your background scripts and move your functions over to your content script.  processing & modifying html should be done in the content script as your background scripts do not have direct access to the dom.  No need for messaging passing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code appears overly complex in a few areas. In particular, the DOM can only be  manipulated from a content script. As wOxxOm mentioned in a comment, it would be a good idea for you to read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

The following complete extension (tested on Chrome and Firefox) changes all non-whitespace characters surrounded by a whitespace character (or the start or end of a line/paragraph) to be within a `<button>`. It does this when an `actionButton` is clicked in the browser user interface.

When the `actionButton` is clicked, the *contentScript.js* file is injected. The content script makes the changes and exits. For this functionality, there is no need for a content script that is sitting in the page waiting to get a message to perform a simple function. You may actually be doing more than you have described/shown with code, but for the functionality mentioned in the Question, injecting the script with [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) is a better, less complicated, and more efficient choice.

I chose not to use jQuery. jQuery is good for many things. In this instance, I did not like the trade-off of loading 90 KiB of code to save just a few characters instead of accomplishing the same thing with stock JavaScript.

I did not take a good look at the code you are using to perform your button-ization. I already had code in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40279806/3773011) which could be easily adapted to perform this task. Given that your question was about how to manipulate the DOM, not about the functionality of your button-ization code, I chose to use the code I was already familiar with.

The extension in action:

[image: button-izing example.com]

*manifest.json*

```json
{
    "description": "Inject content script to make all words in <p> elements buttons",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Button all words in <p>",
    "version": "0.1",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "myIcon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Make Buttons"
    }
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //Inject the script to change the text in <p> to buttons
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file: 'contentScript.js'});
});
```

*contentScript.js*:

```js
(function(){
    function handleTextNode(textNode) {
        if(textNode.nodeName !== '#text'
            || textNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'SCRIPT' 
            || textNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'STYLE'
        ) {
            //Don't do anything except on text nodes, which are not children 
            //  of <script> or <style>.
            return;
        }
        let origText = textNode.textContent;
        let newHtml=origText.replace(/(^|\s)(\S+)(?=\s|$)/mg, '$1<button>$2</button>');
        //Only change the DOM if we actually made a replacement in the text.
        //Compare the strings, as it should be faster than a second RegExp operation and
        //  lets us use the RegExp in only one place for maintainability.
        if( newHtml !== origText) {
            let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
            newSpan.innerHTML = newHtml;
            textNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newSpan,textNode);
        }
    }

    //Find all text node descendants of <p> elements:
    let allP = document.querySelectorAll('p');  // Get all <p>
    let textNodes = [];
    for (let p of allP) {
        //Create a NodeIterator to get the text nodes descendants of each <p>
        let nodeIter = document.createNodeIterator(p,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
        let currentNode;
        //Add text nodes found to list of text nodes to process below.
        while(currentNode = nodeIter.nextNode()) {
            textNodes.push(currentNode);
        }
    }
    //Process each text node
    textNodes.forEach(function(el){
        handleTextNode(el);
    });
})();
```

*myIcon.png*:

[image: Icojam-Weathy-24-tornado.png]

<sup>The code in `handleTextNode` to make changes to text nodes was modified from code in [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40279806/3773011).</sup>