# Need help to debug function change

Tags: javascript, function, codepen

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bgbs/pen/XaNOgM

What I'm trying to do is have the JavaScript select a specific word in td, and wrap it with span for further styling. But it doesn't want to work for some reason. Any ideas?

```html
<style>
  .big {
    font-size: 55px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  function chng() {
    var text = document.getElementByTagName('td').innerHTML;
    var text2 = text.replace('Germany','<span class="big">Germany</span>');
    document.getElementByTagName('td').innerHTML = text2;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Brazil - England - Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="chng()">Try it</button>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no such a method: `document.getElementByTagName`.

Comment: Related: [Change matching words in a webpage's text to buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40576258)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845)

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
function chng(){
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
    var text2 = text.replace('Germany','<span class="big">Germany</span>');
    document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = text2;
}
```

You misspelled `getElementsByTagName()`. It returns HTMLCollection and you need to get the first element, so `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]`.

Comment: Whoa! That's awesome. What does [0] supposed to do?

Comment: it takes the first element of HTMLCollection you got by calling `getElementsByTagName()`. This function returns a collection of many elements, not a single one. `[0]` specifies the exact element you want to take.