# A generic way to extract and replace text from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, rangy

I have two wrappers:

```
function wrapSentences(str, tmpl) {
    return str.replace(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g, tmpl || "<sentence>$&</sentence>")
}
```

and

```
function wrapWords(str, tmpl) {
return str.replace(/\w+/g, tmpl || "<word>$&</word>");
}
```

I use these in our extension to wrap every word and sentence on any webpage the user visits for TTS and settings purposes.

document.body is the most atomic element on every website, but doing `body.innerHTML = wrapWords(body.innerText)` will (obviously) replace any element that was in between the different text nodes, thus breaking (the visual part of) the website. I'm looking for a way to find any closest element around any text without knowing anything specific about that element, so I can replace it with a wrapped equivalent without altering the website in any way.

I found several examples that go to the deepest child, but they all rely on passing something (node or id) the extension has no way of knowing about. We will use rangy for highlighting, but have the same issue... I always end up having to pass a node or id that the extension is unable to be aware of when visiting random sites.

One of the examples that needs a node passed:

```
    function replaceTextNodes(node, newText) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        //Filter out text nodes that contain only whitespace
        if (!/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
            node.data = newText;
        }
    } else if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (let i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            replaceTextNodes(node.childNodes[i], newText);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll be happy to explain it better if needed. I fear my wording may not always be the best, I'm aware of that.

Comment: So what is the issue if you use a recursive function like you presented at the end and pass it `document.body`?

Comment: I have nothing to pass as newText. I need to know the contents of every textnode separately before I can wrap it and pass it as newText. Passing body.innerText would result in every textnode containing the whole body's text.

Comment: Of course, but I assumed you only provided that function as a model. So you are asking us to write a similar function, but that performs the wrapping?

Comment: I simply needs a function that returns every deepest node containing text so that I can wrap it and return the wrapped text to that same node.

Comment: It sounds easier in my head than I'm able to write out, sorry.

Comment: Additional related: [Change matching words in a webpage's text to buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40572679), [Replace text with link with chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40276158)

Comment: Thanks Makyen. It's weird that I haven't found your answers on SO though. Anyhow it did the trick !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is all the text nodes on the page...   [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730309/find-all-text-nodes-in-html-page) might have your answer.
Using the function from the first answer:

Edit: now wrapping text in `<word>` nodes, not just their textContent

```
function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  return a;
}

exp = /(?:(\W+)|(\w+))/g

textNodesUnder(document.body)
    .filter(t => !/^\s*$/.test(t.textContent))
    .forEach(t => {
        let s = t.textContent, match
        while(match = exp.exec(s)) {
            let el
            if(match[1] !== undefined) {
                el = document.createTextNode(match[1])
            }
            else {
                el = document.createElement("word")
                el.textContent = match[2]
            }
            t.parentNode.insertBefore(el, t)
        }
        t.parentElement.removeChild(t)
    })
```

Comment: I don't think assigning HTML codes to `textContent` is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @trincot You're right. I think i got it now.

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow, when I'm back at work.